# How We can Make Parallel Rank Sort To run in O(1) time with any number of processors

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

I know an implementation of parallel rank sort which takes O(log n) time with O(n^2) number of processors,If we employ Concurrent writes then we can get the O(1) running time with O(n^2) processor.
Is there any other method in which we do not use concurrent reads and the running time is O(1).

Comment: I feel like you need to explain your problem more. I had to do research to figure out what rank sort is, and I can't even find the O(log n) parallel rank sort algorithm you're talking about.

Comment: _Any number of processors?_ So, with only one or two processors the rank sorting algorithm would run in O(1)? I highly doubt such an algorithm exists.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison based sort requires at least O(n log n) comparisons. If you do not allow concurrent reads then in time O(1) with n values to sort you can read (or operate on) the values at most O(n) times. So I think an O(1) parallel sort without concurrent reads would have to be pretty exotic. In fact, consider any single value output by the sort, such as the first value, which might be the lowest input value. This depends on all n input values. Without concurrent reads, I think you can represent any process computing a single value as a tree with bounded degree at each node and the value computed at the root. The time taken is the depth of the tree which must be at least O(log n).